# How to plot a wall section

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I plot a wall section with the part of sin graph in the middle like the one in the picture.
[image]

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
         enlargelimits,
         xtick={3.14,6.28},ytick={0.5,1},
         xticklabels={$\frac{\lambda}{2}$, $\lambda$},
         yticklabels={, $1$},
         xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$s(t)$]
         \addplot[domain=0:pi,samples=40,smooth, thick,blue]{sin(deg(x)) };
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) --++(90:3cm);
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,3); 
    \draw (2,0) --++(90:3cm);
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,3); 

    \draw (0,2) sin ++(1,1) cos ++(1,-1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

As `sin` and `cos` drawing operations only draw on interval `[0,\pi/2]`, for a complete period, four operators are needed.

An alternative solution could be `plot` operator.

Both solution are shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) --++(90:3cm);
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,3); 
    \draw (2,0) --++(90:3cm);
    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,3); 

    \draw (0,2) sin ++(0.5,0.5) cos ++(0.5,-0.5) 
                sin ++(0.5,-0.5) cos ++(0.5,0.5);

    \draw[red, scale=2/6.2829, domain=0:6.2829] plot (\x,{1.5+sin(\x r)});

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if I would draw all sin graph in the middle?

Comment: @Ilmionome456    What does it mean?

Comment: I mean that in the middle instead of having half since the graph , have all sin graph